# Programmatically scroll in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scroll

I have a UIWebView which I want to perform a scroll programmatically. So say for instance if you press a UIButton it will scroll a few pixels down or so.

Would this be possible?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better solution. (A button that scrolls a view doesn't sound like good UX to me)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get UIScrollView of Webview first.
After that, you can control your UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge
https://github.com/newyankeecodeshop/GAJavaScript

use Native javascript using Objective-C function like windows.scrollTo(0,1000)

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling *inside* a webview is controllable with JavaScript. Example using [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo):

#### With UIWebView (deprecated)

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    _ = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.scrollTo(0,100);")
}
```

#### With WKWebView (iOS 8+)

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0,100);")
```